# Definite integral implies integrand is the same

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_0^1$ be the space of all functions $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $g'$ is in $L^2[0,1]$ and $g(0)=g(1)=0$, given that $H_0^1$ is a Hilbert space. Let $f\in C[0,1]$. Given that $u\in C^{(2)}[0,1] \cap H_0^1,$ and satisfies for all $v\in H^1_0$ that 
$$ \int_0^1 u'v'dx = \int_0^1 fvdx. $$

Need to show $-u'' = f.$

My try: Using integration by parts and since $v\in H_0^1$, we get $$ \int_0^1 v(f+u'') dx = 0.$$ Taking $v=f+u'',$ we can conclude $-u''=f.$ So, all we need to show is $f+u'' \in H_0^1.$ I am not able to show this with the given information. Any hints or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\{v_n(x)=1-e^{2\pi inx}:n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Then $v_n\in H^1_0,$ and $\int^1_0(f+u'')dx=\int^1_0e^{2\pi inx}(f+u'')dx=c_n$, the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fourier coefficient of $f+u''.$ But $c_n\to 0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma so in fact $c_n=\int^1_0(f+u'')dx=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$ so $f+u''=0$ almost everywhere. But as $f+u''$ is continuous, it is actually zero everywhere.

Comment: Still, don't we need to show that $f+u''$ is an element of $H_0^1?$

Comment: No. You are asked to show that $u''=-f$. You have that $u''+f$ is continuous because $u\in C([0,1])^2$ and $f\in C([0,1])$.  But my proof won't work because $H^1_0$ does not contain all polynomials! Ugh

Comment: My idea was to take $v=f+u''$, which gives $\int_0^1 (f+u'')^2 dx = 0,$ which further implies $f=-u''.$ But to take $v=f+u''$, we need to show that $f+u''\in H_0^1$.

Comment: OK but I think I have a different easier proof now

Comment: Seems promising, but $v_n(0)=1$! For $v_n \in H_0^1$, we need $v_n(0)=v_n(1)=0$ in addition to $v_n' \in L^2$.

Comment: $L^1$ is good enough since the Fejer sums converge uniformly to $f+u''$ but yes I need to rethink this.

Comment: Okay, if you come up with any further thoughts please update the answer.

Comment: I think I have it now.

Comment: Why does $c_n \to 0$ imply $c_n=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: $c_n=\int^1_0(f+u'')$ is constant. Let $n\to \infty$ The LHS is zero. And so so is the RHS

Comment: I did not get this equation $\int^1_0(f+u'')dx=\int^1_0e^{2\pi inx}(f+u'')dx.$ Also, is $v'_n \in L^2?$ I don't think so! ($v'_n= -2\pi i n e^{2\pi i n x} \implies \|v'_n\|_{L^2} = 4 \pi^2 n^2$, thus $v_n$ isn't in $H_0^1.$ )

Comment: $\int (1-e^{2\pi inx})(f+u'')dx=0$ since $1-e^{2\pi inx}$ are in $H_0^1$. Now rearrange. The $v_n$ and all their derivatives are in $L^2$ for all $n$ since we are just integrating continuous functions over a finite interval. Or maybe I am not understanding your comment.

Comment: Okay, the first one is clarified, thanks! Do you agree that $v'_n= -2\pi i n e^{2\pi i n x}$? Now, $  \|v'_n\|^{2}_{L^2} = \int_0^1 |v'_n|^2 dx= 4 \pi^2 n^2$. For $v'_n \in L^2$ we need $ \|v'_n\|_{L^2} $ to be bounded right? That is, as $n\to \infty$, limit of $v'_n$ is no longer in $L^2!$

Comment: All we need is that $each\ v_n$ is $L^2$. The limit of the sequence of derivatives is irrelevant. [Here](http://n.ethz.ch/~lukaswi/download/WS0506/MMP1/solution9-2.pdf) is a proof of the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma for Riemann integrable functions (which is all we are really dealing with here)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than showing $f + u'' \in H^1_0$, let's just note that $f + u''$ is certainly in $L^2$.  And since $H^1_0$ is dense in $L^2$, having $\int v (f+u'') = 0$ for all $v \in H^1_0$ implies $f+u'' = 0$ almost everywhere.  Finally, as Matematleta noted, since $f, u''$ are continuous, $f+u''$ is actually zero everywhere.