# To check something is in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $f_n(x) = e^{2\pi i n x}$. Question: Is $f_n, f'_n \in L^2([0,1])$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

$f_n \in L^2([0,1])$ is true since $\| f_n \|^2_{L_2} =\int_0^1 |f_n|^2dx = 1. $

Is $f'_n \in L^2([0,1])$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? It is **not** since $\| f'_n \|^2_{L_2} =\int_0^1 |f'_n|^2dx = 4\pi^2 n^2, $ right?

This is a follow-up question from [Definite integral implies integrand is the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410163/definite-integral-implies-integrand-is-the-same/3410207?noredirect=1#comment7014383_3410207)

Comment: That is correct. Alternatively, on a bounded domain a function with bounded absolute value is in $L^2$.

Comment: Thanks, can you also look into the attached question? Not able to solve it!

Comment: To clarify, $f_n$ and $f_n'$ are each in $L^2([0,1])$ for every $n$.  However, the sequence $f_n$ is (uniformly) **bounded** in $L^2$ while $f_n'$ is not.

Comment: What is the advantage of one ($f_n$ being uniformly bounded) over the other ($f'_n$ being just in $L^2$) in this case? @NateEldredge

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "advantage".